# Modifying a dictionary collection

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, collections

I currently have a dictionary(string,int) which will hold values like the following

```
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1] , 91
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[2] , 92 
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[2]/FormA1[1] , 93
```

And this collection is created using a simple method CreatePathCollection(string path, int entityKey)

However the challenge I am facing is the following.

Suppose I receive a key and value into my method, which has values like

```
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1] , 94
```

I would like to update the the following keys in the collection from

```
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1] , 91 
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[2] , 92 

 TO 

/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[2] , 91 
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[3] , 92
```

And then Add

```
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1] , 94
```

So the final collection will be

```
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1] , 94
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[2] , 91 
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[3] , 92 
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[2]/FormA1[1] , 93
```

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is your dictionary a `Dictionary<string,int>`? In your example the key is the whole string `/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1]`, and the value is `94`?

Comment: Yes you are right Yacoub!  I will edit my question to add more clarity.

Comment: How about showing us the "simple method CreatePathCollection(string path, int entityKey)"

Comment: First of all, you need to show us some code to see what you tried so far -  here is not a place for puzzles! Second, I'm trying to figure out what is your `path' logic, i.e. are all your keys encoded the way you show in the example, like /sometext[somenumber]/...

Comment: @user3375390, is the problem you are trying to solve inside the `CreatePathCollection` method? Can you explain the syntax of the key? you are linking the reception of some key/value with the update of other items? what is the relation here? You should work on the question to make it more understandable

Comment: Well Yacoub, this is part of a more complex problem and it would require a lot more to even being trying to explain the whole problem. So I just narrowed it down to this part.  Yes I am trying to slove this issue inside the CreatePathCollection method. Well the key is nothing but an XML path that i receive along with another integer as its value.

Comment: But to be more specific, in the key /ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1] , i would be more interested in seeing if there is already a FormA1[1] under Member[1] OR if there are already FormA1[*] which have indexes greater than the one currently being added.  If either of the cases is true then i would have to update the indexes of FormA1[*] in these paths.  Does this give you a little more clarity ?

Comment: @user3375390, So you want to simulate adding a node to a tree? and you need to push siblings one place down so you have a place for the new node?

Comment: @user3375390, must you use `Dictionary<string,int>`? can you create a special class for the key?

Comment: How would the class be, can you give me some more details as to what you are thinking .. i mean how would the class hold  a path like /ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1]  ?

Comment: @user3375390, if you try to insert `..FormA1[1]` and it does not already exists in the dictionary, but you already have `..FormA1[2]` in the dictionary, do you have to do anything?, or simply add `..FormA1[1]` to the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model to represent your key like this:

The following class represents part of the path like `/ReturnState[1]`, and it contains a method (the constructor) to parse the data from a string and another method to convert the data to the string format.

```
public class Part
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public Part(string str)
    {
        int location_of_bracket_start = str.LastIndexOf("[");

        if(location_of_bracket_start == -1)
            throw new Exception("Unexpected format");

        Name = str.Substring(0, location_of_bracket_start);

        string rest = str.Substring(location_of_bracket_start);

        Index = int.Parse(rest.Substring(1, rest.Length - 2));

    }

    public string ConvertToStringFormat()
    {
        return string.Format("/{0}[{1}]", Name, Index);
    }
}
```

The following class represents a full path (e.g. `/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1]`) as a list of parts. It also contains method to construct an the object from a string and to convert to a string.

```
public class NodePath : List<Part>
{
    public NodePath(string path)
    {
        string[] parts = path.Split(new []{"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string part in parts)
        {
            this.Add(new Part(part));
        }

    }

    public string ConvertToStringFormat()
    {
        return string.Join("", this.Select(x => x.ConvertToStringFormat()));
    }
}
```

The following class contains the logic that you need:

```
public class PathClass
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> m_Dictionary;

    public PathClass()
    {
        m_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> Dictionary
    {
        get { return m_Dictionary; }
    }

    public void Add(string path, int number)
    {

        if (m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(path))
            MoveOne(path);

        m_Dictionary.Add(path, number);
    }

    public void MoveOne(string path)
    {
        int number = m_Dictionary[path];

        m_Dictionary.Remove(path);

        var moved_node_path = IncrementPath(path);

        if (m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(moved_node_path))
            MoveOne(moved_node_path);

        m_Dictionary.Add(moved_node_path, number);
    }

    private string IncrementPath(string path)
    {
        NodePath node_path = new NodePath(path);

        node_path.Last().Index++;

        return node_path.ConvertToStringFormat();
    }
}
```

When the consumer tries to add a path, it checks if it exists, if it does, it moves the existing one (increments the index of the last path Part). It does this recursively in case the dictionary also contains an item where we are trying to move to.

I tested this like this:

```
PathClass path_class = new PathClass();

path_class.Add("/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1]" , 1);

path_class.Add("/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1]", 2);

path_class.Add("/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[2]/FormA1[1]", 3);

path_class.Add("/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[2]/FormA1[2]", 4);

path_class.Add("/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[2]/FormA1[1]", 5);
```

I got the following results:

```
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[2], 1
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1[1], 2
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[2]/FormA1[2], 3
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[2]/FormA1[3], 4
/ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[2]/FormA1[1], 5
```

Please note that another way to do this is to use a `Dictionary<NodePath,int>`, this means that you would need to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `NodePath`.

**UPDATE:**

If you don't care about the model, you can replace the `IncrementPath` method with this (and remove the model) for performance reasons:

```
private string IncrementPath(string path)
{
    int location_of_bracket_start = path.LastIndexOf("[");

    if (location_of_bracket_start == -1)
        throw new Exception("Unexpected format");

    string before_bracket = path.Substring(0, location_of_bracket_start);

    string rest = path.Substring(location_of_bracket_start);

    int index = int.Parse(rest.Substring(1, rest.Length - 2));

    index ++;

    return string.Format("{0}[{1}]", before_bracket, index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I end up - not very elegant, but should do the job

```
static void UpdatePathCollection(Dictionary<string, int> target, string path, int entityKey)
{
    int start, index;
    if (path == null || path.Length < 3 || path[path.Length - 1] != ']'
        || (start = path.LastIndexOf('[', path.Length - 2)) < 0
        || !int.TryParse(path.Substring(start + 1, path.Length - start - 2), out index)
        || index < 0) throw new ArgumentException("path");
    var prefix = path.Substring(0, start + 1);
    var nextKey = path;
    var nextValue = entityKey;
    while (true)
    {
        int oldValue;
        if (!target.TryGetValue(nextKey, out oldValue))
        {
            target.Add(nextKey, nextValue);
            break;
        }
        target[nextKey] = nextValue;
        index++;
        nextKey = prefix + index + "]";
        nextValue = oldValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivan .. I think this is what I need !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the strings you use to define the paths will occur in alphabetical order (it will depend on whether you have more than 9 elements per index). In this scenario, you might use SortedDictionary and proceed as follows:

```
private readonly SortedDictionary<string, int> sortedDictionary = CreatePathCollection(path, entityKey); 

public void Set(string path, int index)
{
    sortedDictionary.Remove(path);
    var i = 91;
    foreach (var key in sortedDictionary.Keys)
        sortedDictionary[key] = i++;
    sortedDictionary[path] = index;
}
```

Unfortunately, I may not understand your problem in all detail, but I hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for trying Ronald, But I dont think this would work.

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? I don't fully understand the logic you want to implement